# Map a replacement string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns: absolute path and relative path.
Now say the data is in below format:

```
 absolute path           relative path
 -------------           -------------
 /a/b/c/d/abc.dat                
 /x/y/z/def.dat
 /p/q/r/s/t/test.dat
 /a/b/c/d/abc.dat                
 /x/y/z/def.dat
```

The output should be

```
 absolute path           relative path
 -------------           -------------
 /a/b/c/d/abc.dat        ABCD_PATH       
 /x/y/z/def.dat          XYZ_PATH   
 /p/q/r/s/t/test.dat     PQRST_PATH
 /a/b/c/d/abc.dat        ABCD_PATH       
 /x/y/z/def.dat          XYZ_PATH
```

- If the 1st column contains `/a/b/c/d`, then in the 2nd column it should place some unique string which I give here as `ABCD_PATH`.
- If the 1st column contains `/x/y/z/`, then in the 2nd column it should place some unique string which I give here as `XYZ_PATH`.
- If the 1st column contains `/p/q/r/s/t/`, then in the 2nd column it should place some unique string which I give here as `PQRST_PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a mapping table in a sheet in your excel file (sheet2 for example):

   ```
    ______________________________________
   |   |    A       |      B
   |___|____________|_____________________
   | 1 | Absolute   |   ReplaceBy
   |   |------------|---------------------
   | 2 |/a/b/c/d/   |   ABCD_PATH
   | 3 |/x/y/z/     |   XYZ_PATH
   | 4 |/p/q/r/s/t/ |   PQRST_PATH
   |
   |_________          ___________________
   \ sheet1 /\ sheet2 /\ sheet3 /
    \______/  \______/  \______/
   ```
2. Back to sheet1:

   ```
    ___________________________________________________
   |   |    A               |      B
   |___|____________________|__________________________
   | 1 | absolute path      |   relative path
   |   |--------------------|--------------------------
   | 2 |/a/b/c/d/abc.dat    |   =VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2...    --(hit)-> Ctrl+Shift+Enter
   | 3 |/x/y/z/def.dat      |           |
   | 4 |/p/q/r/s/t/test.dat |           V (copy cell)
   |
   |         __________________________________________
   \ sheet1 /\ sheet2 /\ sheet3 /
    \______/  \______/  \______/
   ```
3. Put in `relative path` `B2` cell this formula:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,
                 MAX((MID(A2, ROW($1:$90), 1)="/")*ROW($1:$90))
                ),
            Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,
            2,
            FALSE)
   ```
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> : it's an array formula, also known as a [CSE formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx).
5. Copy `B2` cell (not the formula) and paste it in the remaining cells in column `B`.

Comment: Thanks Manji the answer perfectly suited the task I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))),"/",""))&"_PATH"` for the path

and `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))))` for the file and extension